# Adaptive selection of Mass values in Hamiltonian Monte-Carlo?

Tags: sampling, simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I know there are good solutions for adaptive selection of path lengths and step-size for Hamiltonian Monte-Carlo (e.g. the NUTS sampler), but for the sampler to work efficiently we also require that the parameters are appropriately normalised, by the use of mass values or a mass matrix.

I'm working on some problems where I can't make a good a priori guess about what appropriate parameter mass values should be, as for the same problem but different data they may change drastically.

It would be nice if there was some way for the mass values to be chosen adaptively as the simulation progresses so that by-hand tuning based on test runs is not needed.

To be specific: for a kinetic energy function
$$
K(p) = \frac{p^T M^{-1} p}{2}
$$
where $p$ is the momentum vector and $M$ is a diagonal mass matrix with $M_{ii} = m_i$, how can we adaptively adjust the mass values $\{m_i\}$ as the simulation advances so as to make it as efficient as possible?

Comment: Isn't this done automatically by Stan?

Comment: @Xi'an I suppose they must do it in Stan actually yes... I'd like to implement it myself in my own system but perhaps it's explained somewhere in the Stan documentation.